# Count numbers and output one char at time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried hard, but I just can't figure it out.

I want to output numbers, but only one character of the number at time. I need to create something like this:

This should be created within a for-loop:
http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/

But as you can see there is more than one character in a cell when number > 10.

The desired result should be for example:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4....

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: If this is homework, it should be tagged with the 'homework' tag.

Comment: Nope. It is for a simple game I want to make myself ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First concatenate the numbers into a string:

```
var s = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 42; i++) s += i.toString();
```

Then loop the characters in the string:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  // output s[i]
}
```

Comment: I think I understand your approach. I'll try it.

Comment: This is what I've wanted. Thanks! [http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/23/](http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/23/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is your jsfiddle updated with my approach: http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/2/

The pertinent aspects that I changed was adding a for loop that processed through the length of the number you were going to output:

```
var str = number.toString(); // the current number as you're looping through
for (var k = 0; k < str.length; k++) {
    var oneLetterAtATime = str.charAt(k); // get the digits one at a time
    output += "<td>" + oneLetterAtATime + "</td>";
}
number++;
```

**Edit:** If you need there to only be nineteen columns, then you'll need to update your column counter for every instance where you are displaying another `<td>` but not looping back around to increment your column counter. I.e.,

```
if (k > 0) {
    j++;
}
```

Here is an updated version displaying how this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/21/

Notably, there isn't a very good way to not go past the 19th column when you are in the middle of displaying a number in the 19th column that has more than one digit.

Comment: this is somehow a correct solution, but as you can see in the second row there are more then 19 columns.

Comment: @MatthiasLoibl, that's because the variable `j` isn't increasing with every td output. This gets you closer: http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/21/

Answer (score 0):

Take all the characters in a string like this:

```
var t = '';
var limit=100;
for (var j = 1; j<= limit; j++) t += j.toString();

var output='';
for (var j = 0; j < t.length; j++) {
  output=output+','+t[i];
}
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jv7H8/22/)

This will server your purpose.

Following is the code, most of it is your code only:

```
rows = 3;
columns = 19;
number = 1;
var str = "";
output = '<table style="width:100%;">';
for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    output += "<tr>";
    for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        output += "<td>" + number + "</td>";
        str +=number;
        number++;
    }
    output += "</tr>";
}
output += "</table>";
$("#game").html(output);

var strvalue="";

$.each(str, function(e,v){
    if (e > 0){
        strvalue = strvalue + ", "+ v;
    }
    else{
    strvalue += v;
    }
});

alert(strvalue);
```